# FORMIO - Collectively populating a form with default values (UNDOCUMENTED? or NOT-SUPPORTED?)

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, formio

### Environment

- Hosting type

  - [] Form.io
  - [x] Local deployment
- Formio.js version: - Version: 4.9.26
- Frontend framework: Angular 8+
- Browser: Chrome
- Browser version: Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

### Expected behavior

to support group (collective) setting `defaultValue` for the form values .
as there is for the individual form component `defaultValue` setting`

### Observed behavior

```
neither `this.tempFormContent.defaultValue =  formSavedData`
```

nor     `this.tempFormContent.defaultValues =  formSavedData` works

**Is this not documented or not supported?**

### Example

```html
<mat-formio [form]="projectFormContent" (submit)="onSubmit($event)"></mat-formio>
```

Individual setting to default value WORKS FINE:

```js
protected tempFormContent:any = {
    "components": [
      {
        "label": "How do YOU define 1",
        "spellcheck": true,
        "tableView": true,
        "validate": {
            "unique": false,
            "multiple": false
        },
        "key": "key1",
        "type": "textarea",
        "input": true,
        "defaultValue": defValuekey1Saved,
        description: "...."
      },
      {
        "label": "How do YOU define 2",
        "spellcheck": true,
        "tableView": true,
        "validate": {
            "unique": false,
            "multiple": false
        },
        "key": "key2",
        "type": "textarea",
        "input": true,
        "defaultValue": defValuekey2Saved,
        description: "...."
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "label": "Save and Next",
        "key": "submit",
        "disableOnInvalid": true,
        "input": true,
        "tableView": false,
        "validate": {
            "unique": false,
            "multiple": false
        }
      }
    ]
  };

//returning the value used in the HTML template
public get projectFormContent():any {
    return this.tempFormContent;
```

BUT is there some group default setting, I've tried this, but NOT working:

```js
protected tempFormContent:any = {
    "components": [
      {
        "label": "How do YOU define 1",
        "spellcheck": true,
        "tableView": true,
        "validate": {
            "unique": false,
            "multiple": false
        },
        "key": "key1",
        "type": "textarea",
        "input": true,
        // "defaultValue": defValuekey1Saved,
        description: "...."
      },
      {
        "label": "How do YOU define 2",
        "spellcheck": true,
        "tableView": true,
        "validate": {
            "unique": false,
            "multiple": false
        },
        "key": "key2",
        "type": "textarea",
        "input": true,
        // "defaultValue": defValuekey2Saved,
        description: "...."
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "label": "Save and Next",
        "key": "submit",
        "disableOnInvalid": true,
        "input": true,
        "tableView": false,
        "validate": {
            "unique": false,
            "multiple": false
        }
      }
    ]
  };

//returning the value used in the HTML template
public get projectFormContent():any {
    this.tempFormContent.defaultValue =  {'defValuekey1':defValuekey1Saved, 'defValuekey2':defValuekey2Saved};
   // this neither works:
   // this.tempFormContent.defaultValues =  {'defValuekey1':defValuekey1Saved, 'defValuekey2':defValuekey2Saved};
    return this.tempFormContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I've came to a solution until the bunch population is natively supported in Formio:

```html
<mat-formio [form]="formContent" (submit)="onSubmit($event)"></mat-formio>
```

and the code:

```js
protected _formContent:any = {
    "components": [
      {
        "label": "How do YOU define 1",
        "spellcheck": true,
        "tableView": true,
        "validate": {
            "unique": false,
            "multiple": false
        },
        "key": "key1",
        "type": "textarea",
        "input": true,
        // "defaultValue": defValuekey1Saved,
        description: "...."
      },
      {
        "label": "How do YOU define 2",
        "spellcheck": true,
        "tableView": true,
        "validate": {
            "unique": false,
            "multiple": false
        },
        "key": "key2",
        "type": "textarea",
        "input": true,
        // "defaultValue": defValuekey2Saved,
        description: "...."
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "label": "Save and Next",
        "key": "submit",
        "disableOnInvalid": true,
        "input": true,
        "tableView": false,
        "validate": {
            "unique": false,
            "multiple": false
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  public get formContent():any {
    if(this.mLShareService.projectInfo.get(PHASE_NAME)){ // populating form with its previously saved values:
      const savedForm:any = this.mLShareService.projectInfo.get(PHASE_NAME); //gets the previously saved form from the external service
      for (let index = 0; index < this._formContent.components.length; index++) {
        const component:any = this._formContent.components[index];
        const componentKey:string = component['key'];
        const componentType:string = (component['type'] as string).toLocaleLowerCase();

        if( //avoids non-dynamic (non-filled) elements
          componentType === 'button' || // a button
          componentType === 'content')  // plain text and not an input field
        { continue;}
        if(savedForm[componentKey]){
          component.defaultValue = savedForm[componentKey];
        }
      }
    }

    return this._formContent;
  }
```

When needed, the **deep population** (if a form contains **panels**) could be provided by checking the type (e.g. `type: "panel"`) and calling the metdhod recursively.